# Avoid repeating values in a group of records

Tags: sql, oracle, etl

I'm sure this has been answered before, but the thing is I don't know how to look for the solution.

I have a Oracle query that gives me this results:

```
ETA     Vessel   Line   POD   SZTP QTY
====    ======   ====   ===   ==== ===
26/12   MAEWIS   MAE    LIV   40RH  23
26/12   MAEWIS   MAE    PBL   40RH  12
26/12   APLMEN   APL    PTR   20DR  44
26/12   APLMEN   APL    TRU   20DR  22
27/12   APLMEN   APL    ECS   40RH   7
27/12   RICKEM   HPL    RTT   40RH  18
```

And what I need is this:

```
ETA     Vessel   Line   POD   SZTP QTY
====    ======   ====   ===   ==== ===
26/12   MAEWIS   MAE    LIV   40RH  23
                        PBL   40RH  12
        APLMEN   APL    PTR   20DR  44
                        TRU   20DR  22
27/12   APLMEN   APL    ECS   40RH   7
        RICKEM   HPL    RTT   40RH  18
```

Maybe also doing it for POD and SZTP, if there are many of those within ETA/VSL/LINE

Is there any way of doing this?

This is my query:

```
select to_char(vv.eta, 'DY-DD/MM') eta,
  a.linevv_vv_vsl_id||'/'||vv.out_voy_nbr vessel,
  a.linevv_line_id line,
  a.discharge_port_id1 pod,
    b.sztp_id sztp,
    b.qty qty
from
  service_orders a,
  service_order_items b,
  vessel_visits vv 
where
   b.so_gkey = a.gkey and
   vv.vsl_id = a.linevv_vv_vsl_id and
   vv.out_voy_nbr = a.linevv_vv_out_voy_nbr and
   sub_type = 'VEPO' and
   ((vv.eta between sysdate and sysdate + 7) or (to_char(vv.ata, 'YYYY-MM-DD') =   to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')))
order by to_char(vv.eta, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

I'm using Pentaho ETL Tool Kettle to run the query, and transform the data stream into an XML. So, if the solution is on the ETL, I could use some help on how to do it there too.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Seems to me that this should be rendered at the presentation level, not in the database query...

Comment: Presentation is an XML file to be injected into an HTML. I'm using Pentaho Kettle ETL to create the XML. I was looking how to do that on Kettle, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Then retag this as a pentaho/kettle question.  I'm not familiar with their products, but surely there is a way to 'group' data, which can then be output as XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I much prefer having all rows defined correctly with all the keys.  However, you can do this, you just need to identify the first rows of each grouping.

```
with t as (<your query here with `to_char(eta, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as eta_yyyymmdd` added>)
select (case when seqnum_eta = 1 then eta else '' end) as eta,
       (case when seqnum_vessel = 1 then vessel else '' end) as vessel,
       (case when seqnum_line = 1 then line else '' end) as line,
       pod, sztyp, qty
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by eta order by vessel, line, pod, sztp, qty) as seqnum_eta,
             row_number() over (partition by eta, vessel order by line, pod, sztp, qty) as seqnum_vessel,
             row_number() over (partition by eta, vessel, line order by pod, sztp, qty) as seqnum_line
      from t
     ) t
order by eta_yyyymmdd, t.vessel, t.line, t.pod, t.sztp, t.qty
```

Comment: What do you mean "inverted"?  The columns are in the same order, the first row should have the value, and the subsequent rows should be blank.

Comment: I understand why.  The problem is that the columns are being redefined in the select clause with the same names.  I just edited it so the `order by` is using the values from the subquery rather than the computed values.

Comment: Outstanding. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The records are backwards, for example:

```
                                    40DR         5
                                    40OT        12
                                FOS 20OT         1
                                GOA 40DR         5
                                LVN 20DR       100
                                LVN 20OT         3
                                MOI 40RH        22
                                VLC 20DR        30
                            MFR ALG 20FR         1
WED-26/12   CATSCHU/934N    CMD GOA 40DR        70
THU-27/12   CAPMORE/027S    CHI GYE 40RH         4
                                    20DR        50
                                    40RH        50
                                    40RH        50
FRI-28/12   URSULRI/066S    MAE PCR 20DR        50
```

This is the final query:

```
with t as (select to_char(vv.eta, 'DY-DD/MM') eta,
  to_char(vv.eta, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as eta_yyyymmdd,
  a.linevv_vv_vsl_id||'/'||vv.out_voy_nbr vessel,
  a.linevv_line_id line,
  a.discharge_port_id1 pod,
    b.sztp_id sztp,
    to_char(b.qty, '9G999') containers,
    case when
      a.notes is null then '   '
      else a.notes end notes
from
  service_orders a,
  service_order_items b,
  vessel_visits vv 
where
   b.so_gkey = a.gkey and
   vv.vsl_id = a.linevv_vv_vsl_id and
   vv.out_voy_nbr = a.linevv_vv_out_voy_nbr and
   sub_type = 'VEPO' and
   ((vv.eta between sysdate and sysdate + 7) or (to_char(vv.ata, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')))
order by to_char(vv.eta, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
select (case when seqnum_eta = 1 then eta else '   ' end) as eta,
       (case when seqnum_vessel = 1 then vessel else '   ' end) as vessel,
       (case when seqnum_line = 1 then line else '   ' end) as line,
       (case when seqnum_pod = 1 then pod else '   ' end) as pod,       
       sztp,
       containers,
       notes
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by eta order by vessel, line, pod, sztp, containers, notes) as seqnum_eta,
             row_number() over (partition by eta, vessel order by line, pod, sztp, containers, notes) as seqnum_vessel,
             row_number() over (partition by eta, vessel, line order by pod, sztp, containers, notes) as seqnum_line,
             row_number() over (partition by eta, vessel, line, pod order by sztp, containers, notes) as seqnum_pod
      from t
     ) t
order by eta_yyyymmdd , vessel, line, pod, sztp, containers, notes
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Plus break on  may be the simplest and most effective instead of writing complicated queries:

```
break on deptno
Select deptno, empno, ename
 From scott.emp
Order by 1
```